# How do I invoke function that accepts a table type argument and returns a table?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have this function that returns a table that shows how many letters are in a person's name:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (name varchar);

INSERT INTO people VALUES ('jill');
INSERT INTO people VALUES ('jimmy');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION letter_count(person people) RETURNS TABLE(letter varchar, count bigint) AS $$
  SELECT letter, COUNT(*) count FROM regexp_split_to_table(person.name, '') letter GROUP BY letter
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

I would like to invoke the function on just the person with name = `jill`, and I expect a result like this, which is returned by manually invoking the query in the function (`SELECT letter, COUNT(*) count FROM regexp_split_to_table('jill', '') letter GROUP BY letter;`):

```
| letter | count |
| ------ | ----- |
| j      | 1     |
| i      | 1     |
| l      | 2     |
```

If I try this query:

```
SELECT letter_count(people.*) FROM people WHERE people.name='jill';
```

I get this as a result:

```
| letter_count |
| ------------ |
| (i,1)        |
| (l,2)        |
| (j,1)        |
```

I've tried a number of other queries (`SELECT * FROM letter_count((SELECT * FROM people WHERE name='jill'));` seemed promising), but with no luck.

Here is a DB fiddle to play to reproduce what I'm seeing: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nBqwyGknRHJeWL5sdoFhhJ/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put such a table function in the `FROM` clause like a table.

Usually a lateral join is the best way to do that:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM people
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL letter_count(people) AS l
WHERE people.name = 'jill';
```